# What is the difference between ‘was really’ and ‘really was’?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The animal was really a puma.
The animal really was a puma.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

> The animal was really a puma.

I would expect this to be a contradiction to a previous assumption.  Something like:

We thought the animal was a big housecat but upon further inspection it was really a puma.

> The animal really was a puma.

I would expect this formation when you are contradicting an incorrect disbelief about what the animal was (in other words the initial assumption was correct, but hard to believe):

Fred thought he saw a puma but the group knew pumas were extremely rare where they were.  Once they got closer, they realized the animal really was a puma.